# jstl variables foreach

Tags: java, jstl

Tengo el siguiente foreach en el controlador

```
for(Paquete p: listaPaquetes){

            entregablePaquete = entregableDao.listaEntregablePaquete(p.getIdPaquete());
            map.put("entregablePaquete"+p.getIdPaquete(), entregablePaquete);


        }
```

y tengo problemas para acceder al objeto "entregablePaquete"+p.getIdPaquete() desde la vista,he tratado hacerlo de la siguiente forma en la vista

```
<c:forEach var="paquetes" items="${listaPaquetes}" varStatus="status">
     <c:set var="id" value="${paquetes.idPaquete}"/>
 <c:forEach var="entregable" items="${entregablePaquete}${id}" varStatus="status">
       ${entregable.nombre}
</c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

pero resulta guardandome en "entregable" simplemente el valor del id y no accede a los demas elementos, la unica forma en la q consigo hacerlo correctamente es definiendo el valor del id en items del foreach, lo cual no es viable pues no voy a conocer ese id siempre

```
 <c:forEach var="entregable" items="${entregablePaquete18}" varStatus="status">
       ${entregable.nombre}
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Compartenos la parte de tu jsp donde importas el map

Comment: ¿Estás segura de que `listaPaquetes` está entre los atributos?

Comment: Y porque no iteras el map directamente?

Comment: el problema como tal es que como lo estoy intentando hacer aca items="${entregablePaquete}${id}" no logro obtener un resultado de este tipo items="${entregablePaquete18}"

Comment: `items` deberia referenciar a una coleccion y tu le estas pasando una cosa extraña, yo pensaria que nisiquiera lo ejecutaria. Porque no puedes iterar el mapa y luego el listado que esta en el mapa?